# Custom buttom navigationBar flutter

Tags: flutter

https://fluttercore.com/flutter-configurable-navigation-bar/
I am trying to use this navigation Bar as an individual class and here is my class code it moves between icons but it dose not  change the pages for ex : when i Press the profile icon it change it color and it appear that this icon has been pressed but the page don't change

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'main.dart';
    import 'package:ff_navigation_bar/ff_navigation_bar.dart';
    import 'elderlyProfile.dart';
    import 'addGelu.dart';
    import 'HomepageElderly.dart';
    import 'Chat.dart';
    
    class addNavigationBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _addNavigationBarPageState createState() => _addNavigationBarPageState();
    }
    
    int selectedIndex = 0;
    
    List pages = [
      HomepageElderly(),
      addGeluPage(),
      chatPage(),
      elderlyProfilePage()
    ];
    
    class _addNavigationBarPageState extends State<addNavigationBarPage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        body:
        pages[selectedIndex];
        return FFNavigationBar(
          theme: FFNavigationBarTheme(
            unselectedItemLabelColor: yellow,
            unselectedItemTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
            selectedItemTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
            barBackgroundColor: nave,
            unselectedItemIconColor: yellow,
            selectedItemBorderColor: white,
            selectedItemBackgroundColor: yellow,
            selectedItemIconColor: Colors.white,
            selectedItemLabelColor: white,
          ),
          selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
          onSelectTab: (index) {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            FFNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'الصفحة الرئيسية',
              iconData: Icons.home,
            ),
            FFNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'إضافة',
              iconData: Icons.add_circle_outlined,
            ),
            FFNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'المحادثة',
              iconData: Icons.chat,
            ),
            FFNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'ملف التعريف',
              iconData: Icons.person,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning your custom navigation bar please don't do that.

do like this,

```
class _addNavigationBarPageState extends State<addNavigationBarPage> {
int selectedIndex = 0;
 
 List<Widget> pages = [
   HomepageElderly(),
   addGeluPage(),
   chatPage(),
   elderlyProfilePage()
 ];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
bottomNavigationBar: FFNavigationBar(),//<-- your custom navigationbar
body: pages.elementAt(selectedIndex),
);
}
```

Comment: the same no thing change

Comment: @Reey I have updated my answer, please check it

Comment: this is also not working when  I return scaffold the page that contain bottom bar disappear

Comment: @Reey can you update your code in the question